Over 300 errors simply from importing 'viem'
I've installed viem
npm install viem
Then I've simply added two imports to a new .ts file.
import { createPublicClient, createWalletClient, http } from 'viem';
import { baseSepolia } from 'viem/chains';

And then compiled it, via a TS task in Gulp, and KABOOM! I have 301 errors.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/types.d.ts(18,65): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/types.d.ts(18,115): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/types.d.ts(20,85): error TS2344: Type 'transaction' does not satisfy the constraint 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
  Type 'Parameters<serializer>[0]' is not assignable to type 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
    Type 'TransactionSerializable' is not assignable to type 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
      Type 'Parameters<serializer>[0]' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
        Type 'transaction' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
          Type 'Parameters<serializer>[0]' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
            Type 'TransactionSerializable' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/types.d.ts(20,162): error TS2344: Type 'transaction' does not satisfy the constraint 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(8,81): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(8,131): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(13,81): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(13,131): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(13,275): error TS2344: Type 'transaction' does not satisfy the constraint 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
  Type 'Parameters<serializer>[0]' is not assignable to type 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
    Type 'TransactionSerializable' is not assignable to type 'OneOf<TransactionSerializableGeneric | TransactionRequestGeneric>'.
      Type 'Parameters<serializer>[0]' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
        Type 'transaction' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
          Type 'Parameters<serializer>[0]' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
            Type 'TransactionSerializable' is not assignable to type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; from: `0x${string}`; gas?: bigint; nonce?: number; to?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; accessList?: AccessList; blobs?: readonly `0x${string}`[] | readonly Uint8Array[]; blobVersionedHashes?: readonly `0x${string}`[]; ... 10 more ...; chainId?: unknown; }'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(15,83): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/accounts/utils/signTransaction.d.ts(15,133): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/acala.d.ts(39,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
  Type '{ data?: `0x${string}`; value?: bigint; nonce?: number; gas?: bigint; to?: `0x${string}`; r?: `0x${string}`; s?: `0x${string}`; v?: bigint; yParity?: unknown; accessList?: undefined; blobs?: undefined; blobVersionedHashes?: undefined; chainId?: number; ... 6 more ...; sidecars?: unknown; }' is not assignable to type 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/anvil.d.ts(40,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/apexTestnet.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/arbitrum.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/arbitrumGoerli.d.ts(31,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/arbitrumNova.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/arbitrumSepolia.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/areonNetwork.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/areonNetworkTestnet.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/astar.d.ts(31,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/astarZkEVM.d.ts(31,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/astarZkyoto.d.ts(31,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/aurora.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/auroraTestnet.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/auroria.d.ts(33,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/avalanche.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/avalancheFuji.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bahamut.d.ts(39,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/beam.d.ts(36,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/beamTestnet.d.ts(36,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bearNetworkChainMainnet.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bearNetworkChainTestnet.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/berachainTestnet.d.ts(33,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/berachainTestnetbArtio.d.ts(33,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bevmMainnet.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bitkub.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bitkubTestnet.d.ts(34,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bitTorrent.d.ts(37,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/bitTorrentTestnet.d.ts(37,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.
/Users/lukepuplett/Git/Tz/src/MyCorp.MyProj.AspNetCoreMvc/node_modules/viem/_types/chains/definitions/blast.d.ts(32,72): error TS2344: Type 'TransactionSerializable<bigint, number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TransactionSerializableGeneric'.

Had to abridge the output as I exceeded the question length lol
TypeScript: 301 semantic errors
TypeScript: emit failed
[17:09:55] 'compileTypescript' errored after 3.96 s

Update
With strict mode enabled:
Found 155 errors in 11 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/viem/_types/clients/decorators/public.d.ts:1015
     1  node_modules/viem/_types/clients/decorators/wallet.d.ts:164
     1  node_modules/viem/_types/types/utils.d.ts:194
    12  node_modules/viem/_types/utils/formatters/transaction.d.ts:51
    12  node_modules/viem/_types/utils/formatters/transactionRequest.d.ts:39

[plus new errors in my own code]

Update 2
Super minimal repro:
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/lukepuplett/ViemRepro
"skipLibCheck": true fixes it but it feels like this just "takes the bulb out of the emergency warning indicator" :-)
It can only be the TS config surely?

This kind of stuff can happen if you use multiple libraries that are incompatible or mismatched versions. If everything is clean, complete and compatible you may get better results reporting a bug.

Thanks. I've since repro'd it with a super minimal project: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/lukepuplett/ViemRepro

The reply here is missing a direct response to anything I said, so I hope it was helpful anyway.

Apologies, I was to abstract. The minimal repro has nothing but viem installed. This is why I'm so confused. The package just doesn't work. I don't understand how something quite widely used can not work in such an obvious way.

I agree, i also think based on what you mention you've done the necessary due diligence to open a bug report.

@Evert thanks, I honestly appreciate the validation!!

Apparently typescript strict mode is required to use Viem.
TLDR; Add "strict": true to your tsconfig.json.
Ref. https://github.com/wevm/viem/issues/1091 and https://viem.sh/docs/typescript

Thanks. I've enabled strict but besides errors in my own code, I still have dozens of errors in viem source.
